# JNA Windows Service Startup Type

Tags: java, windows, service, jna

I've been playing around with JNA and am able to return the status of a Windows Service (i.e. started or stopped) using the code below. I'm not sure how to return the startup type of the service though. I'm sure there are ways outside of JNA, but I would like to continue to use JNA if possible.

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.Library.Handler;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;


public class WindowsService {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager();             
    serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);              
    W32Service service = serviceManager.openService("W32Time", Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);             
    System.out.println(service.queryStatus().dwCurrentState);
    service.close();

     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that while the JNA platform-specific code provides handling for querying a service's status, it does not provide support for querying the service's configuration. That means that to do so, you'll need to provide a JNA mapping for the function in question.

The function you'd want, in this case, is [`QueryServiceConfig()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defined in Advapi32. This function fills in a [`QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, which has a `dwStartType` property which corresponds to the various start-up type values.

Fortunately, mapping a native function is really straight-forward with JNA: you just declare an interface like so (The code examples I'm providing are written in Groovy; the transformation to Java should be pretty straight-forward):

```
interface MyAdvapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    MyAdvapi32 INSTANCE = (Advapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Advapi32", MyAdvapi32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);

    boolean QueryServiceConfig(
        SC_HANDLE hService,
        QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG lpServiceConfig,
        int cbBufSize,
        IntByReference pcbBytesNeeded
    )
}
```

(I derived this using the [definition for `QueryServiceStatusEx()`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.java#L913) in the JNA source, whose parameters closely mirror the parameters for `QueryServiceConfig()`. Note that `QueryServiceStatusEx()` is ultimately the function called by [`W32Service#queryStatus()`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/W32Service.java#L55)).

However, our function requires a `QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG` structure, which is not defined anywhere in JNA. Working from the model of the JNA's [`SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Winsvc.java#L106) definition we end up with something like:

```
class QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG extends Structure {
    public DWORD dwServiceType
    public DWORD dwStartType
    public DWORD dwErrorControl
    public char[] lpBinaryPathName
    public char[] lpLoadOrderGroup
    public DWORD dwTagId
    public char[] lpDependencies
    public char[] lpServiceStartName
    public char[] lpDisplayName

    QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG() {}
    QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG(int size) {
        lpBinaryPathName   = new char[256]
        lpLoadOrderGroup   = new char[256]
        lpDependencies     = new char[256]
        lpServiceStartName = new char[256]
        lpDisplayName      = new char[256]

        allocateMemory(size)
    }
}
```

(Note that this structure is quite a bit more involved than [`SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as `SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS` only has `DWORD` parameters. The allocation sizes I provided in the second constructor, while required for JNA, are probably not the right size.)

Armed with our structure and new interface, we can create a method to call QueryServiceConfig:

```
QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG queryServiceConfig(W32Service service) {
    IntByReference size = new IntByReference()

    MyAdvapi32.INSTANCE.QueryServiceConfig(
        service.handle,
        null,
        0,
        size
    )

    QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG config = new QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG(size.value)

    if (!MyAdvapi32.INSTANCE.QueryServiceConfig(
        service.handle,
        config,
        config.size(),
        size
    )) {
        throw new Win32Exception(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
    }

    return config
}
```

Once we've got all that, using it is pretty simple:

```
QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG config = queryServiceConfig(service)
System.out.println(config.dwStartType)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using JNA 4.2.2:

The problem I was having with this structure was the lpDependencies defined as a doubly null terminated array of strings:

> ### lpDependencies
>
> A pointer to an array of null-separated names of services or load ordering groups that must start before this service. The  **array is doubly null-terminated** .

So I solved this issue by customizing the type mapping:

```
public class QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG extends Structure
    {

        public QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG(Pointer p)
        {
            super(p, ALIGN_DEFAULT, new MyTypeMapper());
        }

        public int dwServiceType;
        public int dwStartType;
        public int dwErrorControl;
        public String lpBinaryPathName;
        public String lpLoadOrderGroup;
        public int dwTagId;
        public TypeMappers.DoubleNullString lpDependencies;
        public String lpServiceStartName;
        public String lpDisplayName;

       @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder()
        {
            return Arrays
                    .asList("dwServiceType", "dwStartType", "dwErrorControl", "lpBinaryPathName", "lpLoadOrderGroup",
                        "dwTagId", "lpDependencies", "lpServiceStartName", "lpDisplayName");
        }

        public static class MyTypeMapper implements TypeMapper
        {

            @Override
            public FromNativeConverter getFromNativeConverter(Class javaType)
            {
                FromNativeConverter result = null;
                if (javaType.equals(TypeMappers.DoubleNullString.class))
                {
                    result = TypeMappers.DoubleNullString.FROM_NATIVE_CONVERTER;
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public ToNativeConverter getToNativeConverter(Class javaType)
            {
                ToNativeConverter result = null;
                if (javaType.equals(TypeMappers.DoubleNullString.class))
                {
                    result = TypeMappers.DoubleNullString.TO_NATIVE_CONVERTER;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

    }
```

I really only cared for the "FromNativeConverter" (DoubleNullString is just a Type marker that has a String[] field):

```
public class MyFromNativeConverter implements FromNativeConverter
{
    @Override
    public Object fromNative(Object nativeValue, FromNativeContext context)
    {
        DoubleNullString result = new DoubleNullString();
        Pointer p = (Pointer) nativeValue;
        int offset = 0;
        List<String> doubleNullList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!(p.getByte(offset) == 0))
        {
            String s = p.getString(offset);
            doubleNullList.add(s);
            offset += s.length() + 1;
        }
        result.lpDependencies = doubleNullList.toArray(new String[doubleNullList.size()]);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Class nativeType()
    {
        return Pointer.class;
    }
}
```

For reference the **ToNativeConverter** should just return a Pointer.class type and if needed, could return a Memory block with the String[] converted to a doubly null terminated array of bytes. For JNA's sake, it just needs to know the "type" and a default "null" value (just so it can initialize the structure).

My method signature then becomes:

```
Memory memory = new Memory(required.getValue());
Advapi32Ex.QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG query = new Advapi32Ex.QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG(memory);
Advapi32Ex.INSTANCE.QueryServiceConfigA(session.getHandle(), query, (int) memory.size(), required);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program from the previous answer as a java class.
IMPORTANT - needs exactly JNA 3.3.0

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ServiceUtil {

    interface MyAdvapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        public MyAdvapi32 INSTANCE = (MyAdvapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Advapi32", MyAdvapi32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
        public boolean QueryServiceConfig(
                Winsvc.SC_HANDLE hService,
                QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG lpServiceConfig,
                int cbBufSize,
                IntByReference pcbBytesNeeded
        );
    }

    public static class QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG extends Structure {
        public WinDef.DWORD dwServiceType;
        public WinDef.DWORD dwStartType;
        public WinDef.DWORD dwErrorControl;
        public char[] lpBinaryPathName;
        public char[] lpLoadOrderGroup;
        public WinDef.DWORD dwTagId;
        public char[] lpDependencies;
        public char[] lpServiceStartName;
        public char[] lpDisplayName;

        public QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG() {}
        public QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG(int size) {
            lpBinaryPathName = new char[256];
            lpLoadOrderGroup = new char[256];
            lpDependencies = new char[256];
            lpServiceStartName = new char[256];
            lpDisplayName = new char[256];
            allocateMemory(size);
        }

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("lpBinaryPathName","lpLoadOrderGroup","lpDependencies","lpServiceStartName","lpDisplayName");
        }
    }
    public static QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG queryServiceConfig(W32Service service) {
        IntByReference size = new IntByReference();
        MyAdvapi32.INSTANCE.QueryServiceConfig(
                service.getHandle(),
                null,
                0,
                size
        );
        QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG config = new QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG(size.getValue());
        if (!MyAdvapi32.INSTANCE.QueryServiceConfig(
                service.getHandle(),
                config,
                config.size(),
                size
        )) {
            throw new Win32Exception(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
        }
        return config;
    }



    public static String checkService(String serviceToCheck) {
        W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager();
        serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
        W32Service service = serviceManager.openService(serviceToCheck, Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

        IntByReference size = new IntByReference();
        MyAdvapi32.INSTANCE.QueryServiceConfig(
                service.getHandle(),
                null,
                0,
                size
        );


        QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG config = queryServiceConfig(service);
        String result = config.dwStartType.toString();
        service.close();
        return result;

    }



}
```